# Running Eclipse JUnit Tests with Gradle Builds of Modular Java (JavaFX) Projects that can also generate executable images with Jlink

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, javafx, junit

I have struggled to find a clean way to work with gradle-built modular Java FX projects (using JDK11), that can produce nice deployable jlink images, whilst still being able to perform Junit tests within the Eclipse IDE.  I have:

- A JavaFX app in my package in the src/main/java folder alongside the necessary info-module.java file.
- JUnit tests in a corresponding package in the src/test/java folder, which obviously doesn’t contain an info-module.java because Eclipse doesn’t tolerate >1 module per project.
- A gradle.build file with:
  plugins { id 'java-library'  id 'application'  id 'eclipse'  id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.12'  id 'org.beryx.jlink' version '2.12.0'}
  dependences {testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'}
  javafx { version = "16"    modules = [ 'javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml' ]}
  mainClassName = "{my-package}.App"
  eclipse {    classpath {file {whenMerged {entries.findAll {it.properties.kind.equals('lib') }.each {it.entryAttributes['module'] = 'true'}}}}}
  jlink {options = ['--strip-debug', '--compress', '2', '--no-header-files', '--no-man-pages'] launcher { name = 'mini'}}

With this configuration,  I can easily run my JavaFX app from within Eclipse (using gradle -> application -> run task) and could build a lovely deployable jlink image (using the jlink task).  However, I could not run JUnit tests within my IDE, which I often like to do to test bits of code and code ideas as I go along – perhaps partly because I’m a bit of an amateur, albeit one with a fair bit of experience.

Having scoured the internet for solutions, I’ve ended up trying various things like adding “requires junit” to the info-module.java file, fiddling with build path configurations to add a JUnit4 library to the Module Path (which would obviously disappear every time I refreshed gradle), and trying JUnit5.  I’ve found nothing satisfactory at all.  Surely Gradle (or perhaps an Eclipse plugin therefor) should have a neat solution?  Is there a one-size-fits-all solution here?

Answer (score 0):

After fiddling around, my solution is:

1. To allow JUnit tests to work:

   a.  Comment out all content within the module-info.java file – this temporarily yields a non-modular project.

   b.  Comment out the eclipse {…} plugin commands in build.gradle – this temporarily breaks the eclipse modular behaviour and jlink task.

   c.  Refresh Gradle.
2. You can then run JUnit tests, and carry on working on your Project, so long as you don’t need modularity or jlink tasks.
3. To restore modularity and jlink tasks for image building:

   a.  Uncomment out (restore) the content of the module-info.java file.

   b.  Uncomment out (restore) the eclipse {} plugin commands in build.gradle.

   c.  Refresh Gradle.

This isn’t too much of a pain, so long as it’s practical to work without modularity whilst performing the JUnit tests.  However, please let me know if there’s a way to avoid all this faffing – perhaps there’s a Gradle (or Eclipse plugin) solution?